# How do you pass html to Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver

I have a webcrawler and I want to pass the html+javascript it retrieves into selenium, is this possible? To clarify I do not want to use webdriver.get to retrieve the page with selenium since my crawler is faster.

Comment: Save it to file and then open it in Selenium with "file://somepath" ?

Comment: After passing it to selenium I want the javascript on the page to run.

Comment: @dilbert ok, so I saved the html page to a file and I use webdriver.get(file path) but the javascript is not loading, I can however get the title of the html page.The javascript did load when I got the html page from a server.

Comment: The javascript is probably AJAX, so the code is expecting to be loaded from a given domain and when it attempts load subsequent data from the 'domain' it fails. If your using a webscraper to get these pages, why not try it the other way; using Selenium to load the page directly and run selenium_browser.page_source, where selenium_browser is your selenium python object. This returns the page source, including AJAX changes made to the document up to that point in time. I've done this for a scraper I've written and seems to work well enough (aside from firefox being slow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up scraping the webpage with PyQt4 on a xvfb server since I was using amazon ec2 which doesn't come with x11. The code below loads the webpage containing JavaScript and waits 7 seconds before returning the html so all the JavaScript will have finished loading.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb

class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.timerScreen = QTimer()
        self.timerScreen.setInterval(7000)
        self.timerScreen.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timerScreen.timeout.connect(self.getHtml)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.timerScreen.start)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()
    def getHtml(self):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()
args = {"nolisten":"tcp"}
vdisplay = Xvfb(**args)
vdisplay.start()
url = 'url here'
r = Render(url)
html = r.frame.toHtml()
print html
f = open("./test.html","wb")
f.write(html.__str__().encode("utf-8"))
f.close()
#stri = str(html).encode("utf-8")
vdisplay.stop()
```